# Get checkbox value within a Listbox after submit button click

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, mvvm, silverlight-toolkit

I have a pivot page with the following list box.
FYI, the list box source was set from code behind after calling and getting from a web service.

```XAML
<phone:PivotItem>
    <phone:PivotItem.Header>
        <TextBlock Text="1. Fault Reported" Style="{StaticResource pivotItemTitle}"/>
    </phone:PivotItem.Header>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" BorderBrush="#FFA68F8F">
            <ListBox x:Name="listBox_Fault" Width="455" Height="550">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="70">
                            <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding ItemName}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </ScrollViewer>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource pageNum}" Text="1/3"/>
    </Grid>
</phone:PivotItem>
```

At the last pivot item, there is a submit button with click event.
When the button clicked, I would like to get the check boxes' content and add the content into a list should they were checked.

How could I access those check boxes and their value please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get the selected check box items, you need to handle "IsChecked" property in Checkbox. First add the following line in your checkbox in xaml.

```
IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected,Mode=TwoWay}
```

And create a property called "IsSelected" in your class as below,

```
public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
```

Then, in submitbutton_click event, use the following code.

```
Items _items = new Items();
Items.wList = listBox_Fault.Items.Cast<Items>().Where(li => (li.IsSelected)).ToList();
```

Where, Items is your class, wList is the List property as follows,

```
public static List<Items> wList;
```

Now you will get the selected checkbox values in your list called wList. Hope it helps.